# Searching on my blog is not working

Tags: search

I've been trying for hours if not a day to try and get my custom `search.php` and `searchform.php` to work and still no success. I've read a lot on these two templates and still no success.

Here is my `search.php`:

```
<div class="post-wrap">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Woops There is no post yet</p>
    <?php endif; ?> 
</div><!-- /.social-media-posts -->
```

Here is my `searchform.php`:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" id="searchform" class="search-form" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="text" id="s" placeholder="Search" class="search-field">
    <input type="submit" value="&#xf002;" id="searchsubmit" class="search-submit">
    <a class="search-close" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
</form>
```

And finally, this is what I use to call my `searchform.php` in my navigation template:

```
<?php get_searchform(); ?>
```

Still nothing works, I'm getting a little discouraged. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `name` attribute. you just need to add it to your input field like this

```
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" placeholder="Search" class="search-field">
```

Any input field is meant to take data for query, the `name` attribute is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually grabbing the search query in your form. You need to include `value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>"` in your input field.

[Here is a link to the docs for the search form.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form%20/%20link)

I think what you're looking for is under the 'Theme Form' heading.